# Problems with TFS and Git

Tags: git, tfs

I've recently started working with TFS, so I'm quite new to it. We've been using Git for a while now, and I'm playing around with git within the TFS web portal. Everything seemed to work good when I initially setup our repo within TFS.

The problem is that the Git repo doesn't seem to be updating when commits are synced to the master branch. Nor are the commits translating over to my Visual Studio when connected to TFS

If I disconnect from TFS within Visual Studio and connect back to the original repo, I'm able to see all commits.

There are 5 of us in total who have been working out of a git repo within Visual Studio. As I continue learning and configuring TFS, they are still working in Visual Studio without TFS. Shouldn't their commits still translate over into the repo within TFS? In either case the code is pointing to the same repo, so it seems that TFS-Git should be up to date in either case.

Any advice and tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your local repo look like? Is a remote properly set to the correct repo?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio, of TFS, of Git you are using? I use this stuff since 3 years so seems a configuration/version mismatch issue.
Are you are exclusively using VS integration (there is no primitive 'sync' operation in Git)? What other tools (e.g. GitKraken, SourceTree, GitHub for Windows) say?

Comment: Can you provide the detailed steps to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have connected the correct branch that you are working on in VS.
2. After committing the changes, you also need to push the commits into TFS.

You can have a quick start with Git and TFS by following this article:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart